# android, observer two different mutable live data at once

Tags: android, android-livedata, concept

I want to observe two different mutable live data at once. is there any way I can achieve this in android,
both data are lies with different ViewModel also.

Comment: Sure, you can attach an observer on two different LiveData at the same time.  If you are having a specific problem with that, please edit the question to show your code and debugging details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) to combine two live data sources into one. Here's a quick example that combines livedata1 and livedata2 from two separate view models into a MediatorLiveData, which emits a data class that contains the result from livedata1 and livedata2. Anytime livedata1 or livedata2 changes, the mediator will be triggered

```
data class CombinedResult(val firstData: DataType1, val secondData: DataType2)

private fun createLiveDataMediator() : LiveData<CombinedResult> {

    val result = MediatorLiveData<CombinedResult>()

    val firstLiveData = myViewModel.getLiveData1()
    val secondLiveData = mySecondViewModel.getLiveData2()

    result.addSource(firstLiveData) {
        result.value = CombinedResult(firstLiveData.value, secondLiveData.value)
    }
    result.addSource(secondLiveData) {
        result.value = CombinedResult(firstLiveData.value, secondLiveData.value)
    }

    return result
}
```